# Move and rename file with double extension using MSBuild

Tags: file, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, file-rename, movefile

In VS MSBuild we move group of files from one folder to another:

```
<ItemGroup>
      <RenameFile Include="Main\App.*" />     
</ItemGroup>    
<Move SourceFiles="@(RenameFile)" DestinationFiles="%(RootDir)%(RenameFile.Directory)NewApp%(RenameFile.Extension)" />
```

It works fine, except one file: `App.exe.config`, because it has double extension and it renamed to `NewApp.config` instead `NewApp.exe.config` (how it should be).

How to fix it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Starting with MSBuild 4.0 we can use [String Item Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/item-functions#string-item-functions), for example Replace:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <RenameFile Include="Main\App.*" />    
</ItemGroup>    
<Message Text="Move: @(RenameFile) -> @(RenameFile -> Replace('App', 'NewApp'))" Importance="High" />
<Move SourceFiles="@(RenameFile)" DestinationFiles="@(RenameFile -> Replace('App', 'NewApp'))" />
```

which works fine.

Comment: Wow, I almost forgot this simple method, when I see this problem, I am always accustomed to using RegexReplace. Because I use it often. Thanks for your sharing :). This answer should be accept as answer, you can accept it after time limit.

Answer (score 2):

> Move and rename file with double extension using MSBuild

It seems you want to move and rename file `App.*`  to `NewApp.*` but keep extension using MSBuild. You can use the [MsBuild Community Tasks](https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks) which have a [RegexReplace](https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks/blob/master/Documentation/TaskDocs.md#RegexReplace) task.

To accomplish this, add the [MSBuildTasks](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSBuildTasks) nuget package to your project, then add following target to do that:

```
  <Target Name="MoveAndRename" AfterTargets="Build">
    <ItemGroup>
      <RenameFile Include="Main\App.*" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Message Text="Files to copy and rename: @(RenameFile)" />
    <RegexReplace Input="@(RenameFile)" Expression="App." Replacement="NewApp.">
      <Output ItemName="DestinationFullPath" TaskParameter="Output" />
    </RegexReplace>
    <Message Text="Renamed Files: @(DestinationFullPath)" />
    <Move SourceFiles="@(RenameFile)" DestinationFiles="@(DestinationFullPath)" />
  </Target>
```

With this target, all `App.*` file are moved and renamed to `NewApp.*`:

[image]

Comment: unfortunately using nugets requires company's approval, which is not so simple